# Throw exception in class declaration

Tags: java, class, exception, throw

I am trying to throw an exception in the declaration of a class. Something like this:

```
class myClass throws A_Dangerous_Exception implements Something_to_Implement {

...

}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that. You probably mean to throw an exception from the class' constructor:

```
class myClass implements Something_to_Implement {
  myClass() throws A_Dangerous_Exception {}
}
```

If you have multiple constructors, each one can have a different `throws` clause if you want:

```
class myClass implements Something_to_Implement {
  myClass() throws A_Dangerous_Exception {}
  myClass(int a) throws A_Dangerous_Exception, A_Not_So_Dangerous_Exception {}
}
```

Then, whenever you instantiate that class, you will have to deal with your exception(s), either by catching them or declaring them in the `throws` clause of the method where you instantiate your class:

```
void myMethod() {
  try {
    new myClass();
  } catch (A_Dangerous_Exception e) {}
}
```

or

```
void myMethod() throws A_Dangerous_Exception {
  new myClass();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Exceptions can only be thrown from methods or constructors. You can do this:

```
class myClass implements Something_to_Implement {

   public myClass() throws A_Dangerous_Exception {
      ...
   }
}
```

Be careful to tidy up any resources such as `FileOutputStream` before throwing an exception from the constructor.

Read: [Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)